# Is it possible to use the_excerpt() instead of the_content() if there is no "Read More" tag in the content?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use the_content() filter on my blog's homepage and use the "More tag" to break the content so that the full post is only available on single post. Sometimes I, or the other authors of the blog forget to insert the more-tage in the content which cause full post output on front page.

I am looking for a solution which looks up wpmore tag in the content and if it not available it throws excerpt instead of full post.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Its good idea but please take care that If you do not provide an explicit excerpt to a post (in the post editor's optional excerpt field), it will display an automatic excerpt which refers to the first 55 words of the post's content.

So the_excerpt() display only first 55 character.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well.  It displays the first 55 words in the post in the more tag is not in the post content, and displays the post content with the more tag in the correct place if it is in the content.

```
<?php if ($pos=strpos($post->post_content, '<!--more-->')): ?>
<?php the_content(); else : the_excerpt(); endif; ?>
```